# Use LAG function on calculated Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to calculate the opening/closing amount of the month on the condition. I am using calculative columns for the same. In My case, the closing of prev month is the Opening for the next month, so I try to use the LAG function. but not able to achieve results.

In the first month the OpeningAmt will be YearAmt

My Table structure is as Follows

| emp_code | year1 | year2 | col_code | paidin | YearAmt | Increment | Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202204 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202205 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202206 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202207 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202208 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 |

and my expected output as follows

| emp_code | year1 | year2 | col_code | paidin | YearAmt | Increment | Used | OpeningAmt | ClosingAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202204 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 | 15000.00 | 16150.00 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202205 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 | 16150.00 | 17300.00 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202206 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 | 17300.00 | 18450.00 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202207 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 | 18450.00 | 19600.00 |
| 330 | 202204 | 202303 | a3 | 202208 | 15000.00 | 1250.00 | 100 | 19600.00 | 20750.00 |

Attempted Query:

```sql
SELECT *,

CASE WHEN year1 = MonthYear THEN NULL ELSE 
LAG(StartMonthClosing,1) OVER (ORDER BY emp_code, col_code, MonthYear) 
END OtherMonthOpening

FROM (
SELECT emp_code, year1,year2,col_code, MonthYear ,YearAmt,  Increment,  Used,
CASE WHEN year1 = MySalaryTable.paidin THEN YearAmt ELSE NULL END StartMonthOpening,
CASE WHEN year1 = MySalaryTable.paidin THEN YearAmt + Increment - Used ELSE NULL END StartMonthClosing
FROM MyreimTable
INNER JOIN MySalaryTable ON MyreimTable.emp_code = MySalaryTable.emp_code
) 
AS P2
```

Comment: So what was your attempt? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @GuidoG, I fix the same

Comment: @Larnu, I am not able to use lag function in case statement on the calculated columns

Comment: Why are you not able to? And you still haven't included your attempt in the question with an [edit].

Comment: @Larnu, I updated my question with my attempted query

Comment: So what isn't working about it? What is the column `MonthYear`? That isn't in your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need data from all previous rows, not just the previous row, you need to use `SUM() OVER()` rather than `LAG() OVER()`. The following gives the desired result from your sample data:

```
SELECT  t.emp_code, 
        t.year1, 
        t.year2, 
        t.col_code, 
        t.paidin, 
        t.YearAmt, 
        t.Increment, 
        t.Used,
        OpeningAmt = SUM(CASE WHEN t.year1 = t.paidin THEN t.YearAmt ELSE 0 END + t.Increment - t.Used) 
                            OVER(PARTITION BY t.Emp_code, t.col_code
                                ORDER BY t.paidin ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
        ClosingAmt = SUM(CASE WHEN t.year1 = t.paidin THEN t.YearAmt ELSE 0 END + t.Increment - t.Used) 
                        OVER(PARTITION BY t.Emp_code, t.col_code ORDER BY t.paidin)
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0532a3694d1741bd2e96eaa452979bda)**

Comment: In `ClosingAmt` you should use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` in case there are duplicate `paidin` values. It's also faster. The default is actually `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which is subtly different